# Стилизация Pandas DataFrame Multiindex

Tags: html, python, pandas, dataframe

Каким образом стилизовать (раскрасить) значения DataFrame из одной части колоночного индекса на основании значений из другой части колоночного индекса?

Пример: Если значение колоночного индекса `['Единица'][2019][10] > 0`, то значение в `['Количество упаковок'][2019][10]` покрасить жёлтым. И так для каждого года и месяца.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Подозреваю, что можно сделать как-то так, но не найду, как именно применить CSS-стиль к конкретной ячейке прямо в функции.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В самом Pandas такого вроде нельзя. Это надо смотреть тулзы какие есть для красивого отображения DataFrame-ов и делать что-то там. Или самому html генерить красивый с раскраской.

Comment: Могу привести пример для обычного DF. Если хотите получить ответ для вашего случая, то потрудитесь пожалуйста привести в вопросе код для создания воспроизводимого DF)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Пример:

Исходный DF:

```
data = {111: {('Единица', 2019, 10): 1.0,
  ('Единица', 2019, 11): 0.0,
  ('Единица', 2019, 12): 0.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 10): 5.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 11): 0.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 12): 0.0},
 112: {('Единица', 2019, 10): 1.0,
  ('Единица', 2019, 11): 0.0,
  ('Единица', 2019, 12): 1.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 10): 2.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 11): 0.0,
  ('Количество упаковок', 2019, 12): 1.0}}
df = pd.DataFrame(data).T.rename_axis("id")
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

решение:

```
def highlight(df, color="yellow"):
    vals = (df.loc[:, pd.IndexSlice["Единица"]] > 0).to_numpy()
    tmp = np.column_stack((np.zeros_like(vals), vals))
    tmp = np.where(tmp==True, f"background-color: {color}", "")
    tmp = pd.DataFrame(tmp, index=df.index, columns=df.columns)
    return tmp

df.style.apply(highlight, color="yellow", axis=None)
```

результат:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

PS в следующий раз настоятельно рекомендую приводить в вопросе воспроизводимый пример данных...

Comment: Отлично! Спасибо. Я тоже нашёл один из вариантов решения (см. ниже), но ваш, конечно, правильнее и, что самое главное, быстрее.

Answer (score 2):

Ещё один вариант того, как можно решить эту задачу.

```
def highlight_visit(row):

    ret = ["" for _ in row.index]

    for year in row['Единица'].index.get_level_values(0).unique():
        for month in row['Единица'].index.get_level_values(1).unique():
            if row['Единица'][year][month] > 0:
                ret[row.index.get_loc(
                    ('Количество упаковок', year, month)
                )] = "background-color: yellow"

    return ret
```

И выгрузка в excel с сохранением форматирования.

```
df_sales_rnc_acts_grp.style.apply(highlight_visit, axis = 1) \
.to_excel('/Users/vadimvitkauskas/Downloads/colored.xlsx', engine = 'openpyxl')
```